# Método alternativo para condição OR

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Gostaria de saber se possui algum meio alternativo para melhorar o desempenho de um select sem precisar usar a expressão OR. Executando somente com um operador de igualdade obtenho o resultado em 30min porém incluindo mais condições com uso do OR há um tempo absurdamente grande para obter o resultado aproximadamente mais 10hs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os campos envolvidos na junção estão devidamente indexados?

Comment: acredito que sim más dê um exemplo de devidamente indexados?

Comment: Ou estão indexados ou não estão, "acredito que sim" não é resposta.

Comment: Você tentou analisar o plano de execução da consulta para verificar os gargalos?

Comment: como faço para analisar?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009

Comment: Tente B.nf_vs_cod_pro in ( a.nf_vs_cod_pro01,a.nf_vs_cod_pro02...)